# Apparent contradiction on finding Extrema of a Functional.

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Imagine you are deriving the Euler-Lagrange Equations. Starting with the functional:
$$
S[F] = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} {F(x, y, y') \; dx}
$$
Then, you add a variation to your functions:
$$
\bar{y}(x) = y(x) + \varepsilon \eta(x) \\
\bar{y}'(x) = y'(x) + \varepsilon \eta'(x)
$$
After that, you plug these varied functions onto your equation, and seek for an $\varepsilon$ that extremizes the functional (basically $dS/d \varepsilon = 0$)

The thing is, I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/VCHFCXgYdvY), and on minute 14:34 it is mentioned that you correct value of $\bar y (x)$ arises when $\varepsilon$ tends to zero.

This feels contradictory to me. As I mentioned before, if you want to extremise the functional, you basically do $dS/d \varepsilon = 0$, but first of all, if $\varepsilon \approx 0$, then $\varepsilon$ is not a variable, because you already know it must have a value near to zero (if not equal), no?

Secondly, suppose for a moment you were on a Calculus class at high school, if we do $dS/d \varepsilon = 0$, we will find a value or values of $\varepsilon$ (assuming the function has at least one extremal point), that would give us the location of these extrema; but imagine (as the video says) that our extremal point arises when $\varepsilon \approx 0$, then we already have our solution, what's the point on doing the derivative? Take this as an analogy. What I was trying to say is that if $\bar{y}(x) = y(x) + \varepsilon \eta(x)$ and $\varepsilon \approx 0$, then you already have your solution: $\bar y(x) = y(x)$ (I know this does not give you any analytical result, but these are the conclusions you arrive to); why on earth allowing $\varepsilon$ to be a variable (when you know is $\approx 0$) and varying your functions like this, would give you a correct result?

What I assume you are seeking for when you do $dS/ d \varepsilon = 0$ are its implications (which are the Euler-Lagrange Equations), not values of epsilon which extremizes the functional. In other words, what $F(x, y, y')$ and $y(x)$ must satisfy.

I know my line of reasoning is probably not correct, so feel free to correct me. I hope I made my explanation clear.

Comment: Hi: What they probably mean is that $\epsilon$ tends to zero because there is no more improvement in the objective function ( after whatever number of iterations, assuming the algorithm is an improvement type of algorithm )  so the function stays constant at this optimal point and the derivative is zero at this optimal point. Atleast this is how a lot of gradient type optimization algorithms work.  So, $\epsilon$ being zero is more of an outcome of the algorithm so it can't just be set to zero.

Comment: The first order methods described here are what I was referring to. I can't guarantee that it carries over to functionals exactly but the concept must be pretty similar. https://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it seems wrong to say that the "correct" value of $\bar{y}(x)$ arises as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

The motivation for the variational argument using $\varepsilon$ is that we want to discover what conditions a minimizer of the functional must satisfy. So we assume that $y$ is a minimizer of the functional. Then we know that the function $g(\varepsilon) = S(y + \varepsilon \eta)$ has a minimum at $\varepsilon = 0$. Then we use calculus to deduce that $y$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations.

To actually find the minimizer then, you would solve the Euler-Lagrange equations and then prove that the solution is indeed a minimizer of the functional. A good example of the entire procedure is the geodesic equation, where the critical point of the functional need not be a minimizer.